# Publicly Accessible GAS HtmlService Form

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to have a publicly accessible HtmlService Form, so that people who are not logged in to a Google Service can access it and use it as a simple html form but still have their response posted to a google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, publish the app as available to anyone, even anonymous.